# What is webRoot in the vscode chrome debugger launch launch config?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am trying to launch the chrome debugger from vscode, but my breakpoints are being passed over and I get the message 'breakpoint set but not yet bound'. I suspect that this is because I have the wrong value for the webRoot property in the launch config.

Documentation on the webRoot property states:

> This specifies the workspace absolute path to the webserver root. Used to resolve paths like `/app.js` to files on disk. Shorthand for a pathMapping for "/"'

I am trying to debug some react components, and I am working within a microservice architecture so my server is a sibling directory of the one I am working in. Therefore, I tried to set the webRoot as `"${workspaceFolder}/../ui-web-server"`.

My question is **what is the webRoot property** (the definition in the documentation is ambiguous to me) and **how does chrome debugger use this property under the hood**?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `webRoot` variable allows you to refer to the directory where your local source files are located.
By default it refers to `${workspaceFolder}`, the place where the files are usually located.

Internally it's used to bind the source maps to the local files. It sets the defaults of `sourceMapPathOverrides` as you see here:

```
const DefaultWebSourceMapPathOverrides: ISourceMapPathOverrides = {
    'webpack:///./~/*': '${webRoot}/node_modules/*',
    'webpack:///./*': '${webRoot}/*',
    'webpack:///*': '*',
    'webpack:///src/*': '${webRoot}/*',
    'meteor://app/*': '${webRoot}/*'
};
```

If your `Visual Studio Code` doesn't hold onto your breakpoints, this can be caused by different reasons:

1. Source maps are not available.
2. Remote debugging of chrome is disabled.
   To enable start chrome with `chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222`.
3. Pattern in the property `url` of your `launch.json` does not match the app's url.
4. Source maps are not bound correctly.
   The property `sourceMapPathOverrides` in the `launch.json` maps the source map path to your local source files.
   If you haven't defined further paths, your `Debugger for Chrome` maps like following:

- `webpack:///./~/*` to `${workspaceFolder}/../ui-web-server/node_modules/*`
- `webpack:///./*` to `${workspaceFolder}/../ui-web-server/*`
- `webpack:///src/*` to `${workspaceFolder}/../ui-web-server/*`
- `meteor://app/*` to `${workspaceFolder}/../ui-web-server/*`

If you're not using `webpack` or `meteor` you might have different source map paths.

To explore the structure of the source maps of my applications I use the `Chrome Developer Tools`. Under `Sources` you can easily navigate through them and discover the paths.
[image]

Here's an example `launch.json`.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach to something",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 9222,
            "url": "http://localhost:8081/*",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/../Application",
            "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
                "webpack://Module/*": "${workspaceFolder}/Module/*"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Hope this helps a bit to understand it and to get it running.

Comment: what will be the path of sourceMapPathOverrides if my sources inside localhost:8069?
I tried `"*/static/*": "${workspaceFolder}/*/static/*"` not working (in odoo after the build all of the apps are merged like "localhost:8069/app1/static" "localhost:8069/app2/static"

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem today in Vue version 3 and using Vue CLI 3.  The answer in this post didn't help.  This solved it - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/vuejs-cli

Only include the preLaunchTask if you have created it (see the article above)

launch.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "vuejs: chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:8080",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "breakOnLoad": true,
      "pathMapping": {
        "/_karma_webpack_": "${workspaceFolder}"
      },
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:/*": "${webRoot}/*",
        "/./*": "${webRoot}/*",
        "/src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
        "/*": "*",
        "/./~/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*"
      },
      "preLaunchTask": "vuejs: start"
    }
  ]
}
```