# Setting webRoot to a correct folder breaks VS Code debugging

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webpack, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am trying to set up a primitive web app with debugging enabled and using webpack.

here is vscode **launch.json**:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "DEBUG CHROME",
            "url": "http://localhost:9000",

            //"webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/public" // this does not work, but is correct, according to documentation

            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}" // this works, but is incorrect, according to documentation
        }
    ]
}
```

Project structure:

[image: project structure]

Does anybody have a clue why debugging breaks(no breakpoints being hit), when webRoot points to correct path - `${workspaceFolder}/public` and works fine for incorrect path?

According tho vs code [**documentation**](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug#launch):

> If you use a url, set `webRoot` to the directory that files are served from

which is clearly wrong in this case.

Minimal example for reproduction is [**here**](https://github.com/danierlr/SO_ChromeDebugTest)

Does anybody know how `webRoot` actually works?

**EDIT**: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52377756/what-is-webroot-in-the-vscode-chrome-debugger-launch-launch-config?rq=1) somebody says, that `webRoot` is:

> Internally it's used to bind the source maps to the local files

Could it be so that in case of webpack, *webRoot* should point to the path where `webpack` command was invoked?

Additionally, there is an [issue](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/closure-webpack-plugin/issues/71) that seems to be related